# Updating fields with python-docx

Tags: python, ms-word, field, python-docx

I am generating a word document from a template using python-docx and I need to update some fields that are embedded in the cover, header and footer sections of the document.

I have searched everywhere and I didn't find any topic explaining how to update fields in MS Word with python-docx. Is it not implemented yet?

Fields I am referring to are the ones located in Advanced Document Properties/Custom.

[Fields configured in Advanced Document Properties menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsJO1.png)

[Adding the fields to the document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhtZ6.png)

[Example of fields in the document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlQ6x.png)

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: Sure, I attach some screenshots:

https://ibb.co/phW44HT
https://ibb.co/8bBDCrx
https://ibb.co/StWb1jX

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you add those images into your question using image tool as well as additional information on what you tried. Please refer to [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thank you and sorry for my bad explanation, it is my very first post here

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution 1

`user:1902513` or `scanny` has yet implemented the `custom_properties` attribute in the main repository of `python-docx` -- and probably not in the near future as he said no developers are active to modify the repository.

My suggestion is to reinstall the module but from different respository copy made by `user:652546` or `renejsum`; [here](https://github.com/renejsum/python-docx).

*[`>> source of solution <<`](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/91#issuecomment-227560642)*

Usage sample is as in [this script](https://gist.github.com/renejsum/0ea621aabd0e4640391ddb3e361f6c02).

Comment: This really works but it does not update the fields after modifying them. I have searched how to update the fields but it does not work for me. Furthermore, that module throws some errors accessing the header of the document.

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution 2

You may change the text of respective custom properties by browsing for its keyword.

Example:

```
from re import compile # regex module to emulate keyword search by pattern 


keyword = re.compile(r'\s*Creator: (?P<creator_name>\w+)\s*')
word_replacement = 'Daniel Serrano'


for _p in doc.paragraphs: # doc = docx.Document(...) 

    found_word = keyword.match(_p.text)

    if found_word: 

        for _r in _p.runs: 
            _r.text = _r.text.replace(
                found_word.group('creator_name'), 
                word_replacement
            )
```

It is better to avoid set change on `_p.text` itself although doable as it may reformat the run (ie. bold, italic, underline dropped).

Comment: Well, this solution works but just deletes the field and replaces it with the text, it does not update the field value.

Comment: Sorry. I was confused since you mentioned 
"_... that are embedded in the cover, header and footer sections..._" 
I thought you were trying to change the document reading output